# how to access the object inside a linked list item

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list which has items. The item has a *searchkey* which I need to access so I can compare it with the string I pass to the *tableDelete* method.

Basically we search the linked list via a city name which is the *searchkey*

like say , Narragansett is the search key and I don't know how to access it after the `head.getItem()` to be able to compare, so I can delete it or w/e I want.

```
c = new City("Narragansett", "USA", 12000);
chart.tableInsert(c);
```

So above a city is a node(item) of the linked list

```
public boolean tableDelete(KT searchKey) {

    if(head.getItem().equals(searchKey)){
        head = head.getNext();
        return true;
    }

    Node current = head.getNext();
    Node prev = head;

    while(current!= null){
        if(current.getItem().equals(searchKey)){
            prev.setNext(current.getNext());
            return true;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate the problem. Its not quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call

```
current.getItem()
```

then you HAVE your object.

Add a . (dot) after and the intellisense will tell you the list of available methods for your object